# Reusing Non-Consumable product code

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Say, in my app, I offer books. 
Correct me if I am wrong, book are non-Consumable products. 
Say, **every book** costs 1$. Do I need to have multiple products in itunes? Or can I have one product and repurchase it (reuse it's product code), for every new request to buy another book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use the same ID for every book, you will get refused with a warning message when one non-consumable is resold.

Have a look at the overview of in-app purchases below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1